# Check access repeated and update table using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I need update the existing value on column `valid_access` on the table `dotable` using a database MySql version 5.7

If an access is repeated by the same `user_code` within one hour only the first access is to be considered valid. On this case I need set value on column `valid_access` equal to 1.

When column `valid_access` equal to **1** the access is valid else the access is null.

I need this output

```
+----+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+
| id | yyyy_mm_dd | hh_mm_ss | user_code | valid_access |
+----+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | 2021-08-02 | 17:10:50 | D17201    |            1 |
|  2 | 2021-08-02 | 15:16:35 | D21145    |            1 |
|  3 | 2021-08-02 | 14:23:52 | D44683    |            1 |
|  4 | 2021-08-02 | 23:00:05 | D45520    |            1 |
|  5 | 2021-08-02 | 21:21:05 | D54107    |            1 |
|  6 | 2021-08-02 | 20:09:00 | D54107    |            1 |
|  7 | 2021-08-02 | 19:45:00 | D42579    |            1 |
|  8 | 2021-08-02 | 13:21:55 | D41373    | NULL         |
|  9 | 2021-08-02 | 13:21:52 | D41373    |            1 |
| 10 | 2021-08-02 | 12:20:33 | D44429    |            1 |
| 11 | 2021-08-02 | 12:10:00 | D23037    |            1 |
| 12 | 2021-08-02 | 08:53:00 | D36687    |            1 |
| 13 | 2021-08-02 | 08:20:00 | D22695    |            1 |
| 14 | 2021-08-02 | 02:02:27 | D42579    | NULL         |
| 15 | 2021-08-02 | 01:48:32 | D42579    |            1 |
| 16 | 2021-08-02 | 01:23:36 | D42579    | NULL         |
| 17 | 2021-08-02 | 01:23:33 | D29942    | NULL         |
| 18 | 2021-08-02 | 01:23:33 | D29942    | NULL         |
| 19 | 2021-08-02 | 01:07:40 | D42579    | NULL         |
| 20 | 2021-08-02 | 01:07:36 | D29942    | NULL         |
| 21 | 2021-08-02 | 01:07:36 | D29942    | NULL         |
| 22 | 2021-08-02 | 00:39:40 | D42579    |            1 |
| 23 | 2021-08-02 | 00:39:31 | D29942    | NULL         |
| 24 | 2021-08-02 | 00:39:31 | D29942    |            1 |
+----+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+
```

Any suggestion?

My table structure and the update query below on **[db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jYfm36Zaf7Fw2ztxwDRsDG/7)**, which offers MySQL 5.7

Comment: Can you explain why for id = 15 you want valid_access = 1? The row with id = 16 is only 25 mins before.

Comment: @forpas because from id = 15, hh_mm_ss = 01:48:32 and id = 22, hh_mm_ss = 00:39:40 (first access valid for D42579) more than an hour has passed... (+ 01:08:52)